# Symfony Dynamically change field attributes after submission

Tags: php, symfony

so I Have this Symfony Form field :

```
$builder
    ->add('field1', CheckboxType::class, [
        'required' => false,
    ])
    ->add('field2', NumberType::class, [
        'disabled' => !$entite->getField1(),
        'required' => $entite->getField1(),
    ]);
```

When the form is build, the field2 attributes are set depending on the entity field1 value.

Then, in the form, field2 HTML attributes are dynamically changes using javascript : if field1 value change, when add or remove 'disabled' / 'required" attributes accordingly.

The problem is, if the field2 is disabled when the form is build and then when enabled id with js, if we submit the form, in PHP the field2 is still disabled.

So I also change attributes in php, by adding this in the FormType:

```
...
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'preSubmit']);
....
public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData(); // here $data['field2'] has the correct value
    $form = $event->getForm(); // here $form->get('field2') value is null and disabled is true

    // trying to remove the field
    $form->remove('field2');

    // And then re-add it with new attributes
    $form
        ->add('field2', NumberType::class, [
            'data'     => $data['field2'],
            'disabled' => !$data['field1'],
            'required' => $data['field1'],
        ]);
}
```

So is there a bettey way to change attributes fields after submission (without removing and adding the field with new attributes) ??

**Edit**

So this works until I set an incorrect value type for field2.
field2 is a NumberType, and is I set an alpha value (like 'azerty')
instead of returning the formview with the fild error message, I get a Symfony Error :

```
A cycle was detected. Listeners to the PRE_SET_DATA event must not call getData() if the form data has not already been set. You should call getData() on the FormEvent object instead.
```

How I can prevent that and get the field error message instead.

Thanks.

Comment: That's the way as far as I know. However you don't need this `$form->remove('field2');` statement as the `field2` will not be added twice, only the options will be replaced.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anwser. So I'll stick with this solution. But now I have another problem related. Can you please check my edit ?